# Form validation inside a loop in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, validation

I have a commenting system in PHP, in which there is loop to fetch articles. every article has a comment form which needs to be validated for null values.

Now problem is there is no limit to the number of these forms and ID of each form is coming from database. I want to validate each form but without writing the script multiple times.

How can i validate the form field for null value without writing script again & again.

Can i create a loop kind of thing in my script which check the field for null values.

My script is like this -

```
function validatecomments()
{
nums = ["1", "2", "3", "4"];
text = "commentform";          //form id is like this - commentform1, commentform2, ...

for (var i = 1; i < nums.length; i++) {
    text = text + nums[i];                       //to create it like form id 

    if (document.text.comment_emp_id.value=="")
    {
        alert("Please enter the Employee ID");
        document.text.comment_emp_id.focus();
        return false;
    }

    if (document.text.comment.value=="")
    {
        alert("Please give some Comments");
        document.text.comment.focus();
        return false;
    }
}

}
```

this is snapshot of the comment form. here are 2 forms with POST button. Problem is i have a number of such forms in a page and i have to check them for null values. I am being forced to write script code multiple times.

[image]

Can anyone help me out.

Comment: Have you even considered trying out something at your end first?

Comment: your question is not very clear please consider to provide more info.. so we can help.

Comment: yes asprin. i have mentioned some code above from my script. the code was working for a page which contain only one form. but when i got multiple forms and i added loop in script, it got worse.

Comment: why you using javasript if you using php... you can validate by php.

Comment: can you provide some example. i tried it using php but with loop i could not handle it.

Comment: the problem is i don't want to write validation code multiple times because i have a number of forms and their ID is coming dynamically.

Comment: i want a loop in the script that iterates my form id like commentform1, commentform2, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are not sending correct value to the script. try this

```
<form name="commentform<?php echo $your_id?>" action="" onSubmit="return validatecomments(this);" method="post">
```

in your script

```
function validatecomments(f)
{
if (f.elements['comment_emp_id'].value=="")
{
    alert("Please enter the Employee ID");
    f.elements['comment_emp_id'].focus();
    return false;
}

else if (f.elements['comment'].value=="")
{
    alert("Please give some Comments");
    f.elements['comment'].focus();
    return false;
}

}
```

May be it helps you.